# How can we track down who modified the SQL User Login Permission / User Mapping and etc

Tags: sql-server, authentication, permissions, tracking, audit-logging

We are currently experiencing permission issue with our SQL account which we already set the permission needed, but suddenly the access was being removed. How can we identify who, how, when removed the permission.

We just added back the permission assigned in the User Mapping which is the db_datareader
We just want to know why it suddenly got removed.

Comment: unless you have set something up in advance to track these changes, you probably will not be able to.

Comment: SQL Server does not log this information automatically; if you don't already have an internal process that logs this, you won't know. Try talking to those that *do* have access to change the permissions; there *should* only be a few of you.

Comment: [This](https://samirbehara.com/2017/12/07/tracking-sql-server-database-permission-changes/) might help, although the article is a few years old and I've not fully tested it myself.

Comment: if default trace doesn't help, there might be information left in the db log you can read using fn_dblog. ALso check sql server logs and extended events sessions to see if there's something there